# Error in copy constructor

Tags: copy, copy-constructor

Am getting an error from the below code

```
class first
{
  public:
  first( const first &f ) 
   {
   }
};

main()
{
  first fobject;
  first sobject = fobject;
}
```

Error am getting is ***"too few Parameter in call to first::first(const first far& )"***

Could some body please help on this ?

Regards,
Aswin.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your code

1 your copy constructor is private
and
2 you have not provided a default empty param constructor to create the first instance of class 'first'

Best practice you should always create a constructor, destructor, copy constructor.

```
class first
{
    public:
        first() {}
        first( const first &f ) {}
};

main()
{
    first fobject;
    first sobject(fobject);
}
```

Comment: Appdjava : I have edited the file, the copy constructor is present in the public access specifier. still am getting the error, but if i define a default constructor, error vanished. Now i want to know, what is the mandatory of coding a default constructor here.

Comment: @Prasath it is not mandatory to create a default constructor in general. But you require one for this code because you are creating 'fobject' without any parameters. So you must provide a default constructor to create that object.